# Change remote 'origin' to 'upstream' with Git

Tags: git, github, terminal, version-control, repository

I've cloned a Git repo from the original source's `upstream` `master` repo to my local machine.

`git remote -v` returns:

```
origin  https://github.com/project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/project.git  (push)
```

But I now know that I need to instead fork this `upstream` `master` branch to my personal GitHub account, clone that, create a new branch, and begin coding (so that I'm not making changes directly to the `upstream` repo, but rather to my own forked `origin` repo). I've forked the `upstream` `master` to my GitHub profile, but don't know how to proceed. I need to get `git remote -v` to look like this:

```
origin    https://github.com/myGitHubProfile/project.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/myGitHubProfile/project.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/project.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/project.git  (push)
```

How can I accomplish this, given that I've already cloned the `upstream` `master` from the original source and it's already set as `origin`?

Comment: See [Ondrej K.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485900/1256452) for a command sequence, but I'll add here that it's not crucial how the remotes come about: you could delete all remotes and re-add them, and the only real cost would be that you typed in a few extra commands. The end result, after running `git fetch --all` or `git remote update`—both do the same thing—is that you'll have all commits from both repositories, find-able through appropriate remote-tracking names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/myGitHubProfile/project.git
```

To give "old" `origin` remote a new `upstream` name and add new remote named `origin`.